# how to make neovim keymap recognize turkish character

Tags: neovim

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-m", function() whatever(1) end) -- works
vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-ö", function() whatever(1) end) -- doesnt work
```

Neovim doesnt recognize my keymap with turkish character. Is there a way of accomplishing this?